# My guitar's high E string keeps snapping at the tuning peg

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, strings, string-gauge

My guitar's high E string has broken eight times just this month. I never overtune or do really high bends. It always breaks around the tuning peg. There was no rust; it was still new. I even tried to use the 10s gauge (I normally use the 9s) and it still snapped.

Answer (score 10):

Seems like the hole the string goes through has sharp edges. Use a tool which is designed to create chamfers for screws, to smooth the rough edges - (a countersinker). Use 3-4 turns of string around the peg no more, no less.

What I often do as well is make sure the last wrap goes round the penultimate one, so the strain isn't actually through the hole. That will probably do the trick with no physical intervention.

Comment: Omg thx imma buy some new strings and try it out

Comment: I agree with Tim. 
If a string breaks consistently at that one place, you have an unusually sharp edge on that tuning peg. 
If you can get a really good magnifying lens, you will be able to see the sharp bit, and it will inform your sanding and smoothing of that surface when you are ready to do the job. 
Good luck!!